# Application Discovery and Load Balancer Duties

Tags: sharepoint-server, topology

[Application Discovery and Load Balancer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/205374/application-discovery-and-load-balancer)

The above link comes close, but I need a slightly more specific answer.

I understand the topology service load balances service applications, but will it also load balance web requests from users to other web front ends in the farm?

Say I have 3 web front ends A,B,C.  If a user is attempting to access my website on A, but A is busy will A send the request to B or C via the topology service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Topology service will not handle end user requests. It only handle the services. read this blog for more explanation on it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2011/02/19/how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-sharepoint-topology-service/

For end user request you need the Load balancer ( 3rd party F5 or builtin) which will balanced the request between the servers.